# I want to extract specific text from txt or json file

Tags: javascript, python, automation

i want to extract specific lines from bunch of text. is there any way to extract all lines start with "text" and end at "}" from this file?  This is just a piece of code I have complete file..

```
        "edge_media_to_caption": {
            "edges": [
                {
                    "node": {
                        "text": **"Summer is a state of mind.\n\n#locobeachresort #locoland #beachlife #batroun"**
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
      
      
        "edge_media_to_caption": {
            "edges": [
                {
                    "node": {
                        "text": **"Sunshine is the best medicine.\n\n#locobeachresort #locoland #beachlife #batroun"**
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which language? You tagged this with 2 different ones? What are expected results? This would be a good time to thoroughly read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: The answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in python then

```
lines = <your json>
for line in lines.split('\n'):
   if 'text' in line:
      <do whatever you want with the line>
```

selects these lines

```
  "text": **"Summer is a state of mind.
  "text": **"Sunshine is the best medicine.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no walk-around for filtering specific lines from files. You'd have to load the text in memory unless you have premature knowledge about the file's structure